# Laravel doesn't save one-to-many relation

Tags: php, laravel, save, one-to-many

Laravel doesn't save one-to-many relation

I tried using the push() and the add() but it just doesn't work even after using the save() method.

I attached the Agent and the Contract model the agent is supposed to have more than one contract or none at all
this was my solution but the contracts doesn't get saved to the Agents !

```php
//Agent class
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Agent extends Model
{
    protected $table = "agent";
    protected $fillable = [
        'agent_name', 'agent_website', 'agent_main_contact_name' ,'agent_moto','agent_business', 'tier', 'class', 'status', 'agent_contact_info', 'agent_image_path','contract'
    ];

    // protected static function boot()
    // {
    //     parent::boot();
    //     //fired whenever a new user is created
    //     static::created(
    //         function ($agent){
    //             $agent->contracts()->create([
    //                 'contract_name' => 'No Contract',
    //             ]
    //         );
    //         //Mail::to($agent->email)->send(new NewUserWelcomeMail());
    //         }
    //     );
    // }

    public function contracts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Contract::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }

}
// Contract model

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contract extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'contract_name', 'contract_start_date', 'contract_end_date' ,'contract_status','contract_description'];
    protected $table = "contract";
    protected $guarded =[];
    public function agent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class);
    }

}


//AgentController where the Agent is created
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->contract);
        $this->validate($request, ['agentName' => 'required', 'agentBusiness' => 'required', 'status' => 'required']);

        $agent = new Agent();
        $agent->agent_name = $request->agentName;
        $agent->agent_website = $request->agentWebsite;
        $agent->agent_main_contact_name = $request->agentMainContactName;
        $agent->agent_moto = $request->agentMoto;
        $agent->agent_business = $request->agentBusiness;
        $tierId = $request->tier;
        $classId = $request->class;
        $statusId = $request->status;
        $agent->agent_contact_info = $request->agentContactInfo;
        $contractId= $request->contract;

        // $data = [
        //     'image' => '',
        // ];
        try
        {
            //dd($request->contract);
           // dd($contractId);
            $contract = Contract::find($contractId);
            //dd($contract);
            // $tier = Tier::find($tierId);
            // $class = Classes::find($classId);
            // $status = Status::find($statusId);
            $agent->contracts->push($contract);

            //dd($contract);


        }
        // catch(Exception $e) catch any exception
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
        {

        }
        $tiers = Tier::select('tier_name')->where('id', $tierId)->get('tier_name');
        foreach($tiers as $tier) {
            $tierName = $tier->tier_name;
        }
        $classes = Classes::select('class_name')->where('id', $classId)->get();
        foreach($classes as $class) {
            $className = $class->class_name;
        }
        $statuss = Status::select('status_name')->where('id', $statusId)->get();

        foreach($statuss as $status) {
            $statusName = $status->status_name;
        }
        $agent->tier = $tierName;
        $agent->class = $className;
        $agent->status = $statusName;



        $agent->save();
        //dd($agent);

        session()->flash('Success', 'Agent Added Successfully');

        return back();

    }
```

Comment: I just tried this
$agent->contracts()->save($contract); and this was the output
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'agent_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `contract` (`agent_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 2019-10-14 08:07:44, 2019-10-14 08:07:44))'

Comment: and if I forced the database to be null and retried this line this was the output
$agent->contracts()->save($contract)
=> App\Contract {#3147
     agent_id: null,
     updated_at: "2019-10-14 08:07:44",
     created_at: "2019-10-14 08:07:44",
     id: 1,
   }
agterwars I tried this
$agent->contracts
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3156
     all: [],
   }

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain this better? Like where exactly the error shows up and what the error is? and maybe what you're trying to accomplish. It's a bit hard to debug this for you without those info.

Comment: I think that you have to save the Agent, $agent->save(); and then you can push your contracts.

Comment: @UdhayanNair 
each agent can have one or more contracts
this store method is what gets called whenever the user send a POST request the server the user choose the contract id from html select element then it get passed to the store method then the method search for the contract with this specific id and make a refrence to it and attach it to the newly created agent
the error is the contract isn't saved

Comment: (at symboled)foreach ($agent->contracts as $contract)
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        {{$contract->contract_name}}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            (at symboled)endforeach
this is the part of html code responsible for displaying the contracts, there is nothing displayed
even after using the Tinker no contracts are saved but the agent's info is saved

Comment: @sochas THANK YOU SO SO SO MUCH IDK HOW BUT IT WORKED
 //dd($request->contract);
           // dd($contractId);
            $agent->save();

            $contract = Contract::find($contractId);
            //dd($contract);
            // $tier = Tier::find($tierId);
            // $class = Classes::find($classId);
            // $status = Status::find($statusId);
            $agent->contracts()->save($contract);
            $contract->save();
            //dd($contract);
THANK YOU

Comment: You are welcome, the agent does not have id until you save it so yo can not save a contract cause of db restriction the agent_id can not be null. :)

Comment: Have you tried `attach`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved it for me
//dd($request->contract); // dd($contractId); $agent->save(); $contract = Contract::find($contractId); //dd($contract); // $tier = Tier::find($tierId); // $class = Classes::find($classId); // $status = Status::find($statusId); $agent->contracts()->save($contract); $contract->save(); //dd($contract);